# Inserting relations into each other with pig?

Tags: apache-pig

Say I have two data sets:

```
A = LOAD 'data1' AS (a1:int,a2:int,a3:int);


DUMP A;
(1,2,3)
(4,2,1)
(8,3,4)
(4,3,3)
(7,2,5)
(8,4,3)

B = LOAD 'data2' AS (b1:int,b2:int);

DUMP B;
(2,4)
(8,9)
(1,3)
(2,7)
(2,9)
(4,6)
(4,9)
```

Is there a way to insert specific tuples from B into A? So the end result would look something similar to:

```
DUMP C;
(1,2,3)
(2,4)
(4,2,1)
(8,9)
...
```

Comment: Please show what things you have tried which have not worked.

Comment: How do you know what tuples from `A` and `B` you need?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please tell us the fields required from A and B and the structure of the output?Is there any primary key involved in the operation?

If there are same fields in A and B You can perform [Join](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/basic.html#join-inner) for the same.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're talking about performing a union.  IF your two relations shared the same schema then you could do this:

```
C = UNION A,B;    -- won't work
```

But, since they don't, you can't union them.  However you could change the schema for B so that it matched A:

```
B = FOREACH B GENERATE 
              b1 as a1, 
              b2 as a2,
              0  as a3; -- dummy value so can union
```

I'm not sure what you mean by selecting "specific tuples" though.  You could of course always filter B such that it only contained tuples matching some criteria.  Can you provide more information about your use case and what you're trying to achieve?